# Converting CommonJS to ES modules

Tags: node.js

I'm doing coding as a hobby and currently working on a new NodeJS project. With my limited knowledge I have the feeling that working with ES Modules is the future (correct me if I'm wrong). Therefore I would like to re-write some CommonJS scripts that I have into ES Modules.

I'm stuck on the following line trying to convert it:
`require('./app/routes/routes')(app)`
(I don't understand what the "(app)" part does at the end).

**routes.js:**

```
module.exports = app => {
    const recipe = require('../controllers/recipe-controller.js');
    var router = require('express').Router();
    // Create a new Recipe
    router.post('/recipe', recipe.create);
    app.use('/api/recipes', router);
  };
```

**server.js:**

```
import express from 'express'
import db from './app/models/index'

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: 'Welcome to bezkoder application.' });
});
require('./app/routes/routes')(app);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line:

```
require('./app/routes/routes')(app)
```

is importing a function and then calling it.  It is logically the same as:

```
const init = require('./app/routes/routes');
init(app);
```

So, to translate this to ESM, you change your routes module to export a named function.  You can then import that named function and then call it (pass `app` to it).

routes.js

```
import express from 'express';
import recipe from '../controllers/recipe-controller.js';

export function init(app) {
    // Create a new Recipe
    const router = express.Router();
    router.post('/recipe', recipe.create);
    app.use('/api/recipes', router);
}
```

server.js

```
import express from 'express'
import db from './app/models/index'
import init from './app/routes/routes';

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: 'Welcome to bezkoder application.' });
});

init(app);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```